# Failed to debug code via aws cloud debugging in IntelliJ

Tags: amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, aws-toolkit

I already succeed enabling cloud debug for an ECS Fargate task in IntelliJ via following [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/zh_cn/toolkit-for-jetbrains/latest/userguide/ecs-debug.html#ecs-prereqs).

Also I configured a debug configuration for the cloud debug enabled task via [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/zh_cn/toolkit-for-jetbrains/latest/userguide/edit-configuration-dialog.html#edit-configuration-dialog-ecs), then I ran the debugging configuration, got below error,

> Retrieve execution role finished exceptionally: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to retrieve execution role from the service: is it set up for debugging?

[image]

Any hint to resolve it. I did not find any doc mentioned execution role requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned it out the error described in question caused by the cloud debug enabled task is **NOT running**.

After reviewing the status of task named with `cloud-debug-` in ECS console, the permission to create **CloudWatch logs stream** required by `cloud debug sidecar` container which is depended by your app container. You have to grant the `logs:CreateLogStream` permission to the execution role of the ECS task.

Also note that `cloud debugging` won't work with ECS tasks with [x-ray enabled](https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-jetbrains/issues/1464) or [appmesh enabled](https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-jetbrains/issues/1463) at this moment.